# Table \caption and \label not working, full table does work in different template, can't figure out what causing it

Tags: springernature, tblr

Like the title says, LaTeX table /caption and /label not working,  full table does work in different template, can't figure out what causing it. I've been trying for days, had others look at it, but can't seem to figure it out. I'm using the SpringerNature template and \documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}

Full example that reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style


\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

\maketitle
I want to reference \ref{tab:1}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{\lipsum[1]}
\label{tab:1}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {Q[180]Q[660]},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{0.94\linewidth},
  cell{2}{1} = {t},
  cell{3}{1} = {t},
  hline{1,6} = {-}{0.08em},
  hline{2} = {-}{},
}
\textbf{Lorem ipsum} &     \\
Lorem ipsum                     & Lorem ipsum  \\
Lorem ipsum                & Lorem ipsum   \\
Lorem ipsum                   & Lorem ipsum \\
Lorem ipsumn                   & Lorem ipsum                            
\end{tblr}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

And the log file (first 50):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.9)  27 JUN 2023 07:02
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**sn-article.tex
(./sn-article.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-05> (./sn-jnl.cls
Document Class: sn-jnl 2019/11/18 v0.1: An authoring template for Springer Journal articles
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fleqn.clo
File: fleqn.clo 2016/12/29 v1.2b Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
\mathindent=\skip47
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \[ robust on input line 50.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 51.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \[ robust on input line 62.
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \] robust on input line 74.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 75.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \] robust on input line 83.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rm on input line 144.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sf on input line 145.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \tt on input line 146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bf on input line 147.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \it on input line 148.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sl on input line 149.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sc on input line 150.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cal on input line 151.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mit on input line 152.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 210.
\columnhsize=\skip50
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
```

and the last 350

```
\l__tblr_d_dim=\dimen259
\l__tblr_h_dim=\dimen260
\l__tblr_o_dim=\dimen261
\l__tblr_p_dim=\dimen262
\l__tblr_q_dim=\dimen263
\l__tblr_r_dim=\dimen264
\l__tblr_s_dim=\dimen265
\l__tblr_t_dim=\dimen266
\l__tblr_v_dim=\dimen267
\l__tblr_w_dim=\dimen268
\l__tblr_a_box=\box77
\l__tblr_b_box=\box78
\l__tblr_c_box=\box79
\l__tblr_d_box=\box80
\g__tblr_table_count_int=\count331
\c@rownum=\count332
\c@colnum=\count333
\c@rowcount=\count334
\c@colcount=\count335
\abovesep=\dimen269
\belowsep=\dimen270
\leftsep=\dimen271
\rightsep=\dimen272
\g_tblr_level_int=\count336
\g__tblr_data_row_key_count_int=\count337
\g__tblr_data_column_key_count_int=\count338
\g__tblr_data_cell_key_count_int=\count339
\g__tblr_array_int=\count340
\l__tblr_key_count_int=\count341
\l__tblr_key_quotient_int=\count342
\l__tblr_key_quotient_two_int=\count343
\l__tblr_key_remainder_int=\count344
\g__tblr_data_str_value_count_int=\count345
\rulewidth=\dimen273
\l__tblr_strut_ht_box=\box81
\l__tblr_strut_dp_box=\box82
\g__tblr_cell_wd_dim=\dimen274
\g__tblr_cell_ht_dim=\dimen275
\g__tblr_cell_head_dim=\dimen276
\g__tblr_cell_foot_dim=\dimen277
\l__column_target_dim=\dimen278
\l__tblr_caption_box=\box83
\l__tblr_caption_left_box=\box84
\l__tblr_row_head_box=\box85
\l__tblr_row_foot_box=\box86
\l__tblr_row_head_foot_dim=\dimen279
\tablewidth=\dimen280
\l__tblr_table_firsthead_box=\box87
\l__tblr_table_middlehead_box=\box88
\l__tblr_table_lasthead_box=\box89
\l__tblr_table_firstfoot_box=\box90
\l__tblr_table_middlefoot_box=\box91
\l__tblr_table_lastfoot_box=\box92
\l__tblr_remain_height_dim=\dimen281
\l__tblr_long_from_int=\count346
\l__tblr_long_to_int=\count347
\l__tblr_curr_i_int=\count348
\l__tblr_prev_i_int=\count349
\l__tblr_table_page_int=\count350
\l__tblr_table_head_box=\box93
\l__tblr_table_foot_box=\box94
\l__tblr_table_head_foot_dim=\dimen282
\l__tblr_table_head_body_foot_dim=\dimen283
\l__tblr_table_box=\box95
\l__tblr_table_hlines_box=\box96
\l__tblr_hline_box=\box97
\l__tblr_row_box=\box98
\l__tblr_col_o_wd_dim=\dimen284
\l__tblr_col_b_wd_dim=\dimen285
\l__tblr_hline_leftskip_dim=\dimen286
\l__tblr_hline_rightskip_dim=\dimen287
\l__tblr_row_ht_dim=\dimen288
\l__tblr_row_dp_dim=\dimen289
\l__tblr_row_abovesep_dim=\dimen290
\l__tblr_row_belowsep_dim=\dimen291
\l__tblr_row_vlines_box=\box99
\l__tblr_vline_box=\box100
\l__tblr_cell_box=\box101
\l__row_upper_dim=\dimen292
\l__row_lower_dim=\dimen293
\l__row_vpace_dim=\dimen294
\l__tblr_vline_aboveskip_dim=\dimen295
\l__tblr_vline_belowskip_dim=\dimen296
\l__tblr_cell_wd_dim=\dimen297
\l__tblr_cell_ht_dim=\dimen298
\l__tblr_diag_box=\box102
)

Package amsthm Warning: Unknown theoremstyle `thmstyletwo' on input line 22.

\c@example=\count351
\c@remark=\count352

Package amsthm Warning: Unknown theoremstyle `thmstylethree' on input line 26.

\c@definition=\count353
(./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
\footinsA=\insert252
\c@footnoteA=\count354
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* bindingoffset: 17.07164pt
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(83.37448pt, 372.0pt, 125.06175pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(73.97716pt, 552.69478pt, 218.37491pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=372.0pt
* \textheight=552.69478pt
* \oddsidemargin=28.17613pt
* \evensidemargin=52.79176pt
* \topmargin=-19.72638pt
* \headheight=5.5pt
* \headsep=15.93355pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=28.45274pt
* \marginparwidth=34.1433pt
* \marginparsep=14.22636pt
* \columnsep=14.22636pt
* \skip\footins=8.0pt plus 4.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemargintrue
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count355
\scratchdimen=\dimen299
\scratchbox=\box103
\nofMPsegments=\count356
\nofMParguments=\count357
\everyMPshowfont=\toks40
\MPscratchCnt=\count358
\MPscratchDim=\dimen300
\MPnumerator=\count359
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count360
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks41
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 31.
(./output.out) (./output.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `output.out'.

\c@lstlisting=\count361
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ninecolors/ninecolors.sty
Package: ninecolors 2022-02-13 vv2022D Select colors with proper color contrast
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2022-06-22 L3 Experimental document command parser
))

LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:1' on page 1 undefined on input line 36.

> Step: init table outer spec.
> Step: parse table options.
> Step: split table.
> Step: init table inner spec.
> Step: parse table inner spec.
> Step: execute table commands.
> Step: calculate cell and line sizes.
> Step: build the whole table.
LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <8.03> on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <4.015> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 55.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <4.015> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 55.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <4.015> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 55.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 55.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+rsfs on input line 55.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <4.015> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 55.


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./output.aux)

 *File List*
  sn-jnl.cls    2019/11/18 v0.1: An authoring template for Springer Journal articles
 article.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
   fleqn.clo    2016/12/29 v1.2b Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
  size10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
   cuted.sty    2021/10/04 v2.0 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
rotating.sty    2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  ifthen.sty    2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
threeparttable.sty    2003/06/13  v 3.0
appendix.sty    2020/02/08 v1.2c extra appendix facilities
hyperref.sty    2022-06-13 v7.00r Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
 nameref.sty    2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2022-06-13 v7.00r Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
   puenc.def    2022-06-13 v7.00r Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi-ltx.sty    2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
 hpdftex.def    2022-06-13 v7.00r Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend-ltx.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend package
with kernel methods
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
breakurl.sty    2013/04/10 v1.40 Breakable hyperref URLs
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
multirow.sty    2021/03/15 v2.8 Span multiple rows of a table
 amsmath.sty    2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
  amsthm.sty    2020/05/29 v2.20.6
mathrsfs.sty    1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
  xcolor.sty    2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
mathcolor.ltx
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
manyfoot.sty    2019/08/03 v1.11 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)
nccfoots.sty    2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
booktabs.sty    2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environment
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx
algpseudocode.sty    
listings.sty    2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
  lipsum.sty    2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
l3keys2e.sty    2022-06-22 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
   expl3.sty    2022-08-05 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2022-08-05 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
  lipsum.ltd
tabularray.sty    2022-06-01 v2022B Typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
  output.out
  output.out
ninecolors.sty    2022-02-13 vv2022D Select colors with proper color contrast
  xparse.sty    2022-06-22 L3 Experimental document command parser
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
   ursfs.fd    1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
 ***********


LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.985pt have occurred.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `output.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 16955 strings out of 477678
 289684 string characters out of 5829488
 692221 words of memory out of 5000000
 35490 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 475486 words of font info for 52 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1151 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 87i,11n,96p,255b,764s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb>
Output written on output.pdf (1 page, 51569 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 39 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 25 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 3 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: make a *complete*  example. One that one can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: My apologies, I've edited the post with a reproducible example

Comment: works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoD8T.png Show your log-file.

Comment: That's interesting... I've added the log file to the post. I hope it's the file you were looking for

Comment: That is not the log file of this document, it contains all kinds of labels that are not in the code here. Please provide the log file of your example only. It would be best to actually add the log file to the question (in a code block) to make the question self-contained. In general the warning `Reference xxx on page n undefined` means that you need to compile the document again for the references to be resolved.

Comment: My apologies, first time the tex exchange and first time asking a question about tex in general.

I can't integrate the log file in the post as it will exceed the character amount. I have updated the log file though

Comment: The log of the example you posted exceeds the character limit?

Comment: Yes indeed, the total length of the post would then become over 30.000. Did you see the log file?

Comment: The new log file is inaccessible (Google asks me to log in, which was not needed with the first version). However, I compiled it myself and indeed the log file I get is slightly over 30000 characters. Most of it is not really relevant though. If you can paste a version with the first 50 and the last 250 lines of the log file then that would probably contain the necessary information and it will be much less than 30k characters. Pasting it in the question also solves Google Drive permissions issues (which is actually one of the reasons why we ask to put everything in the question).

Comment: Another thing that would help is to put the command `\listfiles` in your LaTeX code directly below the `\documentclass` command and then run it again. This produces a list of all packages and versions at the end of the log file. If you do that then add the last 350 instead of 250 lines to your post, because the package list produces an additional 100 lines in the log.

Comment: Your MWE works fine. No errors, referencing of table works as expected.

Comment: The mention of `output.aux` in the log even though the main file is called `sn-article.tex` suggests that you are using Overleaf (or a similar online compiler), is that true? If not, then how do you compile exactly? Does the issue still occur when you start a new project and copy the MWE code there? Does the issue still occur when you compile locally?

Comment: My apologies, I thought I mentioned that in the article. Indeed, I use Overleaf.

I think there's an issue between sn-article document class and the tblr package. Now the table mentioned in the MWE is no issue as I can transform it into a tabular and then it would work. However, later on in the article I have a bigger table that requires the tblr package as it is humongous. In other words, I have to figure a way to make the sn-article document class work with the tblr package